# PyQtThe interface flashes back after joining the thread

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using pyqt to make an interface.There are two threads in the program, one is CameraThread and the other is InferenceThread.The program runs normally when there is only the CameraThread thread, and the interface crashes when the InferenceThread thread joins.
code show as below.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import uic
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys


global_parameter = '1'


# 摄像头进程
class CameraThread(QThread):
    frameCaptured = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def run(self):
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        if ret:
            self.frameCaptured.emit(frame)

        # while True:
        #     ret, frame = camera.read()
        #     if ret:
        #         self.frameCaptured.emit(frame)


# 模型计算
class InferenceThread(QThread):
    resultReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image

    def run(self):
        # 图片预处理
        # image_preprocess = preprocess_image(self.image)
        # 模型处理
        # result = model.predict(np.expand_dims(image_preprocessed, axis=0))
        result = 1
        self.resultReady.emit(result)


# 主窗口
class MainUi(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('./ui/test.ui', self)
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['自动模式', '手动模式'])
        self.ui.action1.triggered.connect(self.open_port_dialog)
        self.ui.action2.triggered.connect(self.open_control_dialog)

        self.camera_thread = CameraThread()
        self.camera_thread.frameCaptured.connect(self.update_camera_feed)
        self.camera_thread.start()

    # 打开端口配置窗口
    def open_port_dialog(self):
        self.portDialog = PortUi()
        self.portDialog.buttonbox.accepted.connect(self.handle_port_accept)
        self.portDialog.buttonbox.rejected.connect(self.handle_port_reject)
        self.portDialog.exec_()

    # 更新串口参数
    def update_port_parameter(self):
        global global_parameter
        print(global_parameter)

    # 端口配置窗口  确认  响应方法
    def handle_port_accept(self):
        self.update_port_parameter()

    def handle_port_reject(self):
        pass

    # 打开控制器参数窗口
    def open_control_dialog(self):
        self.controlDialog = ControllerUi()
        self.controlDialog.buttonbox.accepted.connect(self.handle_control_accept)
        self.controlDialog.buttonbox.rejected.connect(self.handle_control_reject)
        self.controlDialog.exec_()

    # 更新控制器参数
    def update_control_parameter(self):
        print('控制器参数已更新')

    # 控制器参数窗口 确认 响应方法
    def handle_control_accept(self):
        self.update_control_parameter()

    def handle_control_reject(self):
        pass

    # 图像区 图像显示槽函数
    def update_camera_feed(self, frame):
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(
            frame_rgb.data,
            frame_rgb.shape[1],
            frame_rgb.shape[0],
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.ui.label_camera.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(640, 380, aspectRatioMode=Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.ui.label_camera.setScaledContents(True)  # 让图片自适应label大小
        inference_thread = InferenceThread(frame_rgb)
        inference_thread.resultReady.connect(self.handle_inference_result)
        inference_thread.start()

    # 操作区，偏移坐标槽函数
    def handle_inference_result(self, result):
        print(result)


# 串口配置窗口
class PortUi(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('./ui/port.ui', self)
        self.buttonbox = self.ui.buttonBox
        global global_parameter
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(global_parameter)

    def accept(self):
        global global_parameter
        new_parameter = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        global_parameter = new_parameter
        super().accept()


# 控制器参数窗口
class ControllerUi(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('./ui/controller.ui', self)
        self.buttonbox = self.ui.buttonBox

    def accept(self):
        super().accept()


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    mainui = MainUi()
    mainui.ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I think the problem is with the InferenceThread thread, but I don't know exactly what the problem is.
I hope you can give me some guidance, thank you.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to `inference_thread` to stop it being garbage-collected.

Comment: I'm a novice in this area, I don't quite understand what you mean, can you explain it carefully, thank you.@ekhumoro

Comment: `self.inference_thread = InferenceThread(frame_rgb)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! After the modification as you said, the code runs normally and the interface does not crash.@ekhumoro

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.@relent95